# Rails 6 get the difference of the 2 timestamp and assigned to one new field in query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, timestamp

I am working on the rails 6 application with postgresql database, where I have to count to the time of the call.

I have 2 fields in my database one is answered_at(timestamp) and another is end_at(timestamp)

I use the following query, and in that query, I need the difference of (end_at - answered_at) and access in call_duration field

So I can access the call_duration field by attr_accessor but I do not know how to get the difference and set it into the query.

My original query is

```
@in_app_calls = InAppCall.where("caller_user_id =? OR receiver_user_id =?", chat_user&.first&.id, chat_user&.first&.id)
           .group_by(&:call_type) unless chat_user.nil?
```

following is my database record

```
<InAppCall id: 1, caller_user_id: 10, receiver_user_id: 61, call_type: "audio", call_answered: true, answered_at: "2020-07-16 04:24:17", end_at: nil, created_at: "2020-07-08 09:58:36", updated_at: "2020-07-16 04:24:17", on_going_updated_at: nil>
```

I may get nil value in answered_at(timestamp) or end_at(timestamp) field, in that case, I will not consider that record.

Can anyone help me with the query?

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to do this is to use virtual attributes that ActiveRecord basically creates on the fly for you when you modify the `select` list. You can do it like so:

```rb
user_id = chat_user&.first&.id
@in_app_calls = InAppCall.
  select("in_all_calls.*, EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM end_at - answered_at)::int AS call_duration").
  where("caller_user_id = :user_id OR receiver_user_id = :user_id", user_id: user_id).
  where.not(answered_at: nil, end_at: nil).
  group_by(&:call_type) if user_id.present?
```

Note the additional field that I'm creating with `AS call_duration` => ActiveRecord simply turns this into an `attr_reader` on the model, so you can do `@in_app_calls[0].call_duration` and such things like you would with any regular column.

I also took the liberty of cleaning up your handling of the `user_id` – I hope it's correct this way, otherwise you should have no trouble reverting this bit back to your original.

Comment: How can I get the time in seconds in from (end_at - answered_at)?

Comment: I've updated my answer to cast the interval into seconds. If you want microseconds as well, simply leave out the `::int` cast. I've also included a direct filter for `answered_at` or `end_at` being `NULL`.

Comment: I implement your query bit it gives me nil when I try to access the call_duration_seconds even for the fields like end_at and answered_at which is not nil

Comment: I doublechecked this against some of my source code and it works just fine. Are you sure that both columns are set for the record(s) in question? Maybe the issue is somewhere else?